# ¿Concatenar información cuando se encuentre información repetida en un objeto?

Tags: javascript, objeto

Buenas tardes compañer@s, me podrian ayudar con el siguiente problema que tengo, tengo un json que se ve algo así:

```
[
  {
    "id": 166948,
    "nombre": "MEDICARTE SAS",
    "tipo nombre": "nombre ESPECILIZADA",
    "direccion": "CL 83 # 16 A - 44 PISO 4",
    "telefono": 6017456670,
    "departamento": "BOGOTA D.C.",
    "municipio": "BOGOTA D.C.",
    "regional": "CENTRO"
  },
  {
    "id": 166999,
    "nombre": "ART MEDICA S.A.S.",
    "tipo nombre": "nombre ESPECILIZADA",
    "direccion": "CR 94 A # 99 C - 27 BR LA CHINITA",
    "telefono": 6044444994,
    "departamento": "ANTIOQUIA",
    "municipio": "APARTADO",
    "regional": "ANTIOQUIA"
  },
  {
    "id": 167000,
    "nombre": "ART MEDICA S.A.S.",
    "tipo nombre": "nombre ESPECILIZADA",
    "direccion": "CR 94 A # 99 C - 27 BR LA CHINITA",
    "telefono": 6044444994,
    "departamento": "ANTIOQUIA",
    "municipio": "APARTADO",
    "regional": "ANTIOQUIA"
  },
  {
    "id": 900304869,
    "nombre": "SICOR - CENTRO CLÍNICO Y DE INVESTIGACIÓN EN HIPERTENSIÓN Y RIESGO CARDIOVASCULAR",
    "tipo nombre": "nombre ESPECILIZADA",
    "direccion": "Cl 19 # 42-40 LOMA DINERS",
    "telefono": 6040007,
    "departamento": "ANTIOQUIA",
    "municipio": "MEDELLIN",
    "regional": "ANTIOQUIA"
  }
]
```

Y lo que quiero hacer es concatenar la información de la propiedad municipio a la propiedad nombre con javascript, usando de la ayuda de un foreach, esto con el fin de que yo lo pueda usar para llenar un select.

Algo así se vería
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que pasa es que yo intente hacer de la forma en que si en la posición que el me recorre son los mismos datos con la posición siguiente me lo concatene el municipio y hasta cierto modo funciono, pero cuando estamos en la ultima posición de datos repetidos no va a funcionar ya que para el siguiente giro del for los datos cambian me podrían ayudar con este problema, les agradecería mucho.

El código que estaba usando era este:

```
 arrayContenidoInternoIpsOrdenado.forEach((elementArray, key) => {
  if (key != arrayContenidoInternoIpsOrdenado.length - 1) {
    if (arrayContenidoInternoIpsOrdenado[key + 1]["nombre"] === elementArray.nombre) {
      elementArray.nombre = elementArray.nombre + " - " + elementArray.municipio;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Tú dices "la posición que el me recorre son los mismos datos con la posición siguiente me lo concatene el municipio". Puedes explicar mejor esta parte, y el porqué de ello?

Comment: Claro el key esta en 0, seria la posición actual que el for recorre cuando digo la siguiente posición es cuando key valga 1, entonces lo que hago es preguntar si mis datos de key valga 0 son exactamente iguales para cuando key valga 1.

Comment: Pero lo que no entiendo, es porque razón haces eso, cual es la lógica de negocio que hay detrás?? que tiene que ver el dato con el dato posterior?. Ayudaría, también, tener una salida esperada. Saludos

Comment: Recuerdo haber visto preguntas parecidas. No sé si se pueda considerar duplicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar un objeto para contar la cantidad de veces que se repite cada nombre, corriendo 1 vez tu arreglo, y después, vuelves a correr el arreglo pero ahora sólo consultando si la propiedad del objeto, con el nombre, se repite más de una vez, algo así

```js
const myArr = [
  {
    id: 166948,
    nombre: "MEDICARTE SAS",
    "tipo nombre": "nombre ESPECILIZADA",
    direccion: "CL 83 # 16 A - 44 PISO 4",
    telefono: 6017456670,
    departamento: "BOGOTA D.C.",
    municipio: "BOGOTA D.C.",
    regional: "CENTRO",
  },
  {
    id: 166999,
    nombre: "ART MEDICA S.A.S.",
    "tipo nombre": "nombre ESPECILIZADA",
    direccion: "CR 94 A # 99 C - 27 BR LA CHINITA",
    telefono: 6044444994,
    departamento: "ANTIOQUIA",
    municipio: "APARTADO",
    regional: "ANTIOQUIA",
  },
  {
    id: 167000,
    nombre: "ART MEDICA S.A.S.",
    "tipo nombre": "nombre ESPECILIZADA",
    direccion: "CR 94 A # 99 C - 27 BR LA CHINITA",
    telefono: 6044444994,
    departamento: "ANTIOQUIA",
    municipio: "MEDELLIN",
    regional: "ANTIOQUIA",
  },
  {
    id: 900304869,
    nombre:
      "SICOR - CENTRO CLÍNICO Y DE INVESTIGACIÓN EN HIPERTENSIÓN Y RIESGO CARDIOVASCULAR",
    "tipo nombre": "nombre ESPECILIZADA",
    direccion: "Cl 19 # 42-40 LOMA DINERS",
    telefono: 6040007,
    departamento: "ANTIOQUIA",
    municipio: "MEDELLIN",
    regional: "ANTIOQUIA",
  },
];

let nameObj = {};

myArr.forEach((element) => {
  if (nameObj[element.nombre]) {
    nameObj[element.nombre] += 1;
  } else {
    nameObj[element.nombre] = 1;
  }
});

myArr.forEach((element, index) => {
  if (nameObj[element.nombre] > 1) {
    myArr[index].nombre = element.nombre + " " + element.municipio
  }
});

console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es muy acertada, el único problema es que también necesito usar las demás propiedades, como puedo agregarlas a tu ejemplo o sea para que el resultado final sea mi mismo objeto inicial, pero con la propiedad nombre cambiada, cuando se repite.

Comment: Deja edito mi respuesta

Comment: Listo, ya edité mi respuesta, eso debería de funcionarte

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono perfectamente.